# Integration by parts. Cyclic effect.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve $\int_0^lf(s)sin(s)ds$ for any $f(s)$ but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Here there is one of my attempts using integration by parts trying to take advantage of trigometric functions cyclic phenomena:
$\int_0^lf(s)sin(s)ds = [-f(s)cos(s)]_0^l + \int_0^lf'(s)cos(s)ds = [-f(s)cos(s)]_0^l+[f(s)cos(s)]_0^l + \int_0^lf(s)sin(s)ds.$

I think this is a closed path because I get the obvious $\int_0^lf(s)sin(s)ds=\int_0^lf(s)sin(s)ds$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: (+1) Good effort! Despite the fact that it didn't lead you anywhere--in fact, it *can't* lead you anywhere, since you did a thing, and then undid it--you're far from the only person to take this approach (I've done so, for example). This post is highly informative, if only as a cautionary tale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your approach it is possible to avoid the cyclic phenomena and get something useful. As you surely know, integration by parts works choosing a part of the function to be $u$ and the rest to be $dv$, so the integral is $\left[uv\right]_0^l-\int_0^lvdu$. The problem is that in the first time you choose $u=f(s)$ and $dv=\sin(s)ds$, and then you switch this selection, which produces the going back. If you solve $\int_0^lf'(s)\cos(s)ds$ by setting $u=f'(s)$ and $dv=cos(s)ds$, and keep going on this way, you are going to get $$\int_0^lf(s)\sin(s)ds=\left[-f(s)\cos(s)+f^{(1)}(s)\sin(s)+f^{(2)}\cos(s)-f^{(3)}\sin(s)-f^{(4)}\cos(s)+...\right]_0^l=\left[-\cos(s)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}f^{(2n)}(s)+\sin(s)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}f^{(2n+1)}(s)\right]_0^l$$ which is not a pretty beatiful answer, but that's what you'll get with integration by parts. You can also try using the Taylor expansion of $f$. Hope that helps!